# How is HttpContextBase being registered with ninject? I didn't explicitly bind it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I created a binding for HttpContextBase in my NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices method, but when I try to reference it in my controllers or services I get an error message.

Here's the binding:

```
kernel.Bind<HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(context => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).InRequestScope();
```

Here's the error message:

```
Error activating HttpContextBase
More than one matching bindings are available.
Activation path:
 2) Injection of dependency HttpContextBase into parameter abase of constructor of type HomeController
 1) Request for HomeController

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for HttpContextBase only once.
```

If I remove the binding, then it appears to do what I wanted (resolves to HttpContextWrapper), but I'm wondering how this gets registered?

Comment: Why does your `HomeController` take an `HttpContextBase` constructor parameter? Why are you registering the `HttpContextBase` in your DI container? That's completely meaningless.

Comment: This is a bit of a contrived examplee and I understand your feelings on the matter, but I'm curious as to HOW its being wired behind the scenes.  I typically control what is registered, and in this case, it appears that ninject is doing it for me.

Comment: There you go, you answered your question by yourself: `it appears that ninject is doing it for me`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Why is it meaningless?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> but I'm wondering how this gets registered?

Look at the source code of the [`MvcModule.cs`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/MvcModule.cs) and your question will be immediately answered:

```
this.Kernel.Bind<HttpContext>().ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current).InTransientScope();
this.Kernel.Bind<HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(ctx => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).InTransientScope();
```

Comment: In case anyone runs into this same problem: as of v3.2.1 the `HttpContextBase` binding [has been removed](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/commit/41b0136be6d265f82396d382ac87d999eb981a87) from the `MvcModule.cs` file. You must add your own binding.

Comment: You don't need your own binding, it's registered from Ninject.Web.Common here: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common/WebCommonNinjectModule.cs

Comment: I'm using v3.2.1 of Ninject.MVC myself, and it's still binding it's own HttpContextBase.  I assume that's because even though MvcModule.cs may not be doing it anymore it's still being automatically bound in Ninject.Web.Common which Ninject.MVC uses.

Answer (score 3):

I see the binding being registered by Ninject.Web.Common v3.2.3.0

If you are trying to mock the binding in your unit tests, you must remove it first like this:

```
// WebCommonNinjectModule loads HttpContextBase. We need to remove it
var httpContextBaseBinding = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(System.Web.HttpContextBase)).FirstOrDefault();
kernel.RemoveBinding(httpContextBaseBinding);
kernel.Bind<System.Web.HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(m => httpContextBaseMock.Object);
```